# How to calculate address and jump in one step in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

This question is about x86-64 assembly. Code is written in AT&T style syntax.

I want to do a jump to `%rax+%rdx*8`, but this seems to be possible only with 
two instructions:

```
lea (%rax,%rdx,8),%rax
jmp *%rax
```

However, since there is a way to do an even more complex thing:

```
jmp *(%rax,%rdx,8) # jumps to the address stored at address %rax+%rdx*8
```

I wonder if there is also a way of jumping directly to `%rax+%rdx*8`.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @Matt, this is not a duplicate. While the two questions are somewhat related, this question asks about how to calculate a jump address, but "x64: How to do a relative jmp *%rax?" is about how to make a jump RIP-relative or not RIP-relative. In fact, I'm trying to solve two different things here.